# Perl, Children, and Shared Data

Tags: mysql, multithreading, perl, multiprocessing, children

I'm working with a database that holds lots of urls (tens of thousands). I'm attempting to multi-thread a resolver, that simply tries to resolve a given domain. On success, it compares the result to what's currently in the database. If it's different, the result is updated. If it fails, it's also updated.

Naturally, this will produce an inordinate volume of database calls. To clarify some of my confusion about the best way to achieve some form of asynchronous load distribution, I have the following questions (being fairly new to Perl still).

1. What is the best option for distributing the workload? Why?
2. How should I gather the urls to resolve prior to spawning?
3. - Creating a hash of domains with the data to be compared seems to make the most sense to me. Then split it up, fire up children, children return changes to be made to parent
4. How should returning data to the parent be handled in a clean manner?

I've been playing with a more pythonic method (given that I have more experience in Python), but have yet to make it work due to a lack of blocking for some reason. Asside from that issue, threading isn't the best option simply due to (a lack of) CPU time for each thread (plus, I've been crucified more than once in the Perl channel for using threads :P and for good reason)

Below is more or less psuedo-code that I've been playing with for my threads (which should be used more as a supplement to my explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish, than anything).

```
# Create children...
for (my $i = 0; $i < $threads_to_spawn; $i++ )
{
    threads->create(\&worker);
}
```

The parent then sits in a loop, monitoring a shared array of domains. It locks and re-populates it if it becomes empty.

Comment: If you want to use processes instead of threads, just write your code with threads, and then swap `use threads` for `use forks`. This also allows childs to “return” data, just like with threads.

Comment: "plus, I've been crucified more than once in the Perl channel for using threads :P and for good reason". you shouldn't have been. Proper use of threads if perfectly efficient.

Comment: @ikegami: assuming everything in the domain resolution code is thread safe...

Comment: @ysth, He was told he was crazy for using threads (presumably for imagined performance issues), not for using code that isn't thread-safe in threads. Two different things.

Comment: but we don't know what he was told he was crazy for using threads *for*

Comment: @ysth, that's the point. No reason appears to have been given, so there's awful good chance it's the usual cargo-culted prejudice.

Comment: not given the "for good reason"; that makes it sound more like the usual case of a newcomer to perl assuming threads are lightweight things with trivial creation cost experiencing a correction.

Comment: @ysth, They do have a trivial creation cost in a worker model.

Comment: @ysth, ...and elsewhere too! Base cost for starting a thread: 0.000,005 seconds. Forking: 0.002,500 seconds.

Comment: if you want to fight the cargo culting, providing misleading numbers like that doesn't help.  rerun your test with code that actually does something (e.g. add `use DateTime; use DBIx::Class;`) (and measure memory cost, too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the start of a persistent worker model.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 1.03 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 5;

sub work {
   my ($dbh, $job) = @_;
   ...
}

{
   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();

   for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
      async {
         my $dbh = ...;
         while (my $job = $q->dequeue()) 
            work($dbh, $job);
         }
      };
   }

   for my $job (...) {
      $q->enqueue($job);
   }

   $q->end();
   $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

Performance tips:

- Tweak the number of workers for your system and workload.
- Grouping small jobs into larger jobs can improve speed by reducing overhead.

Comment: are you assuming all the jobs are queued at once? it sounded like they may only be available in batches, and ideally you wouldn't restart all your worker threads for each batch

Comment: @ysth, No, they can be added until you call `end`. You can postpone calling `end` as long as you want. They will be performed as they come in. The workers will block until a job comes in if there are none to perform.

Comment: @ikegami, a persistent worker model is exactly what I was going after. Thank you for the model! Would you suggest moving from threads to subprocesses?

Comment: @ysth the jobs are literally pulling a row (or a group of rows) from an array (blocking until done) and chugging along. The parent blocks when the queue empties, to reload it, broadcasting when complete.

Comment: @geudrik, Would I suggest *moving* to processes? No, not unless it solves a problem. If you have a problem with workers crashing, processes might work better. // On the other hand, if you're simply asking whether you should be *using* threads or processes, use whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: @ysth, No worries. If it wasn't clear to you, it was surely unclear to others too.

Comment: @ikegami final question for this post: is using the parent to keep a shared queue populated the most efficient way of passing work off to the children, given the scenario described above?

Comment: As I alluded in my answer, if the work units are too small, you'll have a lot of overhead as you're constantly accessing the queue. If you're dealing with a high throughput of jobs, you'll benefit from grouping them into bigger jobs.

Comment: Not sure what it means for a worker to "block pulling rows from an array", so I can't comment if the overall structure is the best for you.